# How can I force the x axis to use column entries

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a chart using a data frame which has TimePeriod as 201811, 201812, 201901, ..., 202006 which I want to use as the x axis values and plot against the y values (Total lives). See figure here:

[image]

However, when I plot the figure the x axis shows up as 201825, 201850, 201875, 201925,..., 202025. This clearly makes no sense and I cannot figure out how to force python to plot the desired x axis.

I am assuming it is something in xticks but I haven't has any luck. I have also tried manually entering all x axis values as `labels = ('201811', '201812', '201901', ...)` but this did not work either.

Is there any way to achieve the desired outcome?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

aggregated_lives_plt = aggregated_lives.plot(x= 'TimePeriodId', y='TotalLives', kind = 'line')
plt.title('Aggregated Optional Benefit Certs Since Nov-2018')
plt.xlabel('Time Period')
plt.ylabel('Total Certs (Lives)')
plt.show()
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Timeperiod` is integers, you can convert it to string:

```
aggregated_lives['TimePeriodId'] = aggregated_lives['TimePeriodId'].astype(str)
```

then use your plot command.